# Sequelize - Nested Column Syntax with two nested includes

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to create WHERE conditional that includes an OR relationship between the "person.name" column, or the "person->associates->friends.username" column. Embedding the where condition in the include (Friends model) creates an AND relationship which isn't what i need.

For simplicity's sake, an example:

```
Person.findAll({
where: {
  $or: [
    {
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      '$associates.friends.userName$': 'John'
    }
  ]
},
include: [
  {
    model: Associates,
    as: 'associates',
    include: [
      model: Friends,
      as: 'friends'
    ]
  }
]
})
```

Doing this creates the following error:
"Unknown column 'associates->friends.userName' in 'where clause'"

the Join renames the column to 'associates.friends.username' but the nested column syntax seems to want to re-name that first period "." to a "->". Any support for doing this?

EDIT: Adding a Picture of what has got me the closest to what i need.

[image]

Sequelize version 5.21.2 currently.

Comment: U can add required: false option inside the include object, to filter related documents without effecting outer parent model.

Comment: Kindly check the following link if it helps - https://pastebin.com/0k4dKgGW

Comment: Rohit - unfortunately i've adding the where in the nested include of "friends" model, but that creates an AND relationship between the two wheres. I need an OR relationship

Answer (score 0):

Believe i found the cause of the issue here..

```
Person.findAll({
where: {
  $or: [
    {
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      '$associates.friends.userName$': 'John'
    }
  ]
},
include: [
  {
    model: Associates,
    as: 'associates',
    include: [
      model: Friends,
      as: 'friends'
    ]
  }
]
})
``

This code **does** work correctly. in my example I also have a *"limit"* property included and it is the inclusion of this *"limit"* that changes the query and causes the error. the above query parameters on their own seem to do the trick!
```